# node-sync can't make function synchronize

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a function in nodejs, some reason I want it synchronize before do another step.
Currently I use node-sync:

My function like this:

```js
function downloadImageIcon(url,path,ori,callback){
    var request = require('request');
    //Sync(function() {
        request.get({url: url, encoding: 'binary'}, function (err, response, body) {
            console.log("start load: " + path);
            //Sync(function() {
                fs.writeFile( ori, body, 'binary', function (err) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log(err);
                    else {// if success then we need to convert it
                        console.log("converting : " + path);
                            fs.writeFileSync( path, imagemagick.convert({
                                srcData: fs.readFileSync(ori),
                                width: 1024,
                                height: 1024,
                                resizeStyle: 'aspectfill', // is the default, or 'aspectfit' or 'fill'
                                gravity: 'Center' // optional: position crop area when using 'aspectfill'
                            }));
                        callback();

                    }
                //});
            });
            console.log("end load: " + path);

    });
    //})
}
```

The business of this function is:

1. download image from server
2. store in local
3. convert to different resolution

I use this function like this:

```
            paramMgr.getTemplateParam(comp.id, function (params) {
                //Tao folder
                var comp_folder_image = config.base_folder_url + comp.id + '/image';
                mkdirp(comp_folder_image);
                params.forEach(function(param){
                    if(param.varname == "icon"){
                        //return param.value;
                        Sync(function() {
                            downloadImageIcon.sync(null,config.imgUrl + param.value, comp_folder_image + '/icon.png', comp_folder_image + '/icon_ori.png', function () {
                                console.log("done loading");
                            })
                        });


                    } else if(param.varname == "splashScreen"){
                        //return param.value;
                        Sync(function() {
                            downloadImageSplash.sync(null,config.imgUrl + param.value, comp_folder_image + '/splash.png', comp_folder_image + '/splash_ori.png')
                        });

                    }
                });

            });
```

Because I have many   paramMgr.getTemplateParam call depend on comp.id, after getTemplateParam, I need to do another business for this comp, and this step need the data generate from getTemplateParam.

So I need all function in getTemplateParam synchronized to get Final data for next step.

Comment: You want this function to be processed before you can do something else, right?

Comment: exactly what i want @krakig!

Comment: why don't you just do something like that : `downloadImageIcon(myurl,mypath,myori,function(err) {//function was processed, can do something else});`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `imagemagick.convert` incorrectly. It is Asynchronous function. It also takes callback. Read documentation for you module more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergey said before, imagemagick.convert is asynchronous.

```
fs.writeFileSync('mini.png', imagemagick.convert({
    srcData: fs.readFileSync('./orange.png'),
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024,
    resizeStyle: 'aspectfill', // is the default, or 'aspectfit' or 'fill'
    gravity: 'Center' // optional: position crop area when using 'aspectfill'
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("finished converting")
    })
);
console.log('callback');
```

output

```
callback
finished converting
```

One solution :

```
fs.writeFileSync(path, imagemagick.convert({
    srcData: fs.readFileSync(ori),
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024,
    resizeStyle: 'aspectfill', // is the default, or 'aspectfit' or 'fill'
    gravity: 'Center' // optional: position crop area when using 'aspectfill'
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("finished converting")
      callback();
    })
);
```

Comment: thanks @krakig, i try your solution but still not working :(, please see full explain source i have edit above and give some advance for me :).